# Can't access node.js script from web browser

Tags: node.js

I installed node.js and socket.io in my CentOS 6.4 server. It is running parallel with Apache, with Apache as main server (port 80)

I wrote a simple Hello world script to test node.js installation:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    response.write('Hello World\n');
    response.end();
}).listen(8088);

console.log('Server started');
```

If I run it in command line I get 'Server started'. But when I tryh to access it via web  browser, typing http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8088 it never loads. I've tried to use many other port numbers with no success. I have to ips in my server, but neither of them work, nor my domain addres under those ips.

How could I fix it?

**EDIT: node,js is installed in another server, and I'm trying to access it via webbrowser from outside this server.**

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `localhost:8088`?

Comment: Node.js is installed in another server, not mine. I'm trying to connect from outside that server.

Comment: Can you `curl http://localhost:8088` and get output on the server console itself? If so, it's indicative of a firewall or something else preventing traffic on that port.

Comment: It may be worth testing to see if Apache responds with a plain html page just to test if the server can indeed even be "reached." This way you can narrow down the context to see if it's just Node.js or Apache, or something in your network.

Comment: I've changed my script to listen at port 9100 (I didn't try to open it in any way). `node script.js` returns what is expected to. And `curl http://localhost:9100` returns **Hello World**, as expected too. So, is it a firewall problem then? I'm running on CentOS 6.4 server, how could I open this port? i've tried everything I found and nothing seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: Just to check: `netstat -an | grep 9100` returns `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4433                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN`. No idea of what this problem might be about...

Comment: If Apache and node.js are running on the same server and you can access Apache but not node.js. Try closing Apache and starting node on 80. If it shows `Hello World`, then you have a firewall problem (ports are getting blocked).

Comment: There is a large site already running on Apache port 80, can't turn it off. It all seems to be about ports. But I run `telnet 127.0.0.1 9100` and it returns 
`Trying 0.0.0.0...
Connected to 0.0.0.0.
Escape character is '^]'.`
Even if I try: `curl http://www.domain.tld:9100/` I get the expected "Hello world" output. How could I manage this? I've tried what they all said about openning ports, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Just to be sure that it is not a node.js problem. Could someone please check if port `9101` is open at `198.1.122.129` and/or `198.57.216.208`?. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to open port 8088 by firewall on server.
see `man iptables`